# Joining tables when there are duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a simple table such as the below with the first column containing currency and the second containing the corresponding amount.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMefo.png]

If I want to convert the real_amount in each row in the image above to USD, how do I use SQL to join to the below table? To explain the below, in row 1 it's saying that 1 AED is 0.239336 EUR

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iubJ3.png]

I am using DB Browser for SQL Lite and analysing CSV data. I am a beginner when it comes to SQL.

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) What is the logic for the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the tables on the type of currency and then use a formula to convert the values.

I haven't tested this, but this should be close:

```
SELECT
   CURRENCY,
   real_amount,
   first.real_amount * second.rate AS converted_amount_as_USD
FROM first
   INNER JOIN second
   ON first.CURRENCY = second.ccy
   AND second.base_currency = 'USD'
```